# Implicit insert statement

Tags: oracle

I'm having trouble inserting some values into a copy of a table. Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO copy_d_events
VALUES (110, 'Ayako Anniversary',
        07-Jul-04, 
        'Party for 50, sixties dress, decorations', 
        'Not Determined', 
        245, 79, 240, 6655);
```

Oracle is giving me this error:

> ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Anyone help a guy out?

@TheEwook I also tried:

```
INSERT INTO copy_d_events
(ID, Name, Event_ Date, Description, Cost, Venue_ID, Package_ Code ,Theme_Code ,Client_ Number) VALUES (110, 'Ayako Anniversary',07-Jul-04,'Party for 50, sixties dress, decorations',245, 79, 240, 6655);
```

Comment: Did you really have spaces in the middle of "Package_ Code", "Event_ Date", and "Client_ Number"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [to_date](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function:

```
INSERT INTO copy_d_events
VALUES (110, 'Ayako Anniversary',
        to_date('2004/07/07 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 
        'Party for 50, sixties dress, decorations', 
        'Not Determined', 
        245, 79, 240, 6655);
```

> The `to_date` function allows you to define the format of the date/time
>   value

**EDIT**

```
ID  NAME                EVENT_DATE  DESCRIPTION                             COST     VENUE_ID PACKAGE_CODE  THEME_CODE CLIENT_NUMBER 
100 Peters Graduation   14-MAY-04   Party for 200, red, white, blue motif   8000    100 112 200 5922 105    Vigil wedding   28-APR-04   Black tie at Four Season hotel  10000   220 200 200 6133
```

Based on the columns data you posted, I think that the problem is `'Not Determined'` value. If it is a numeric column, you probably have to query this way:

```
INSERT INTO copy_d_events
VALUES (110, 'Ayako Anniversary',
        to_date('2004/07/07 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 
        'Party for 50, sixties dress, decorations', 
        0, 
        245, 79, 240, 6655);
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that to and its giving me invalid number ..

Comment: Can you post the `copy_d_events` columns?

Comment: ID NAME EVENT_DATE DESCRIPTION COST VENUE_ID      PACKAGE_CODE THEME_CODE CLIENT_NUMBER
100 Peters Graduation 14-MAY-04 Party for 200, red, white, blue motif 8000 100 112 200 5922
105 Vigil wedding 28-APR-04 Black tie at Four Season hotel 10000 220 200 200 6133

Comment: OKAY so I finally figured it out lol, I had to insert 0 into the party cost, because it has not been determined yet, and I also had to insert the date in the way you suggested. Thanks alot for all the help! PS  I could not insert NULL because it gave me a column error or whatever..

Comment: Your column is not nullable, so you can't insert a NULL value. Probably 0 works fine for your needs, but think that NULL is more suitable for the "Undefined" value

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem with the date `07-Jul-04`. You can't just write the date like this.

You may try that with the [to_date](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function:

```
INSERT INTO copy_d_events
VALUES (110, 'Ayako Anniversary',to_date('01/07/2004','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'Party for 50, sixties dress, decorations', 'Not Determined', 245, 79, 240, 6655);
```

It is highly recommended to specify the column name when you insert data in your database.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Doc: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: darn this is frustrating, i tried the to_date function and now it is giving me another error: invalid number

Comment: Can you post the SQL query you've tried?

Comment: It says I need 10 reputation to post a picture, but I have 10 and it still wont let me...lol

Comment: You still can edit your post with the SQL query you've tried instead to post a picture.

Comment: I guess I'm confused, because the code that I posted INSERT INTO copy_d_events
VALUES (110, 'Ayako Anniversary',
        07-Jul-04, 
        'Party for 50, sixties dress, decorations', 
        'Not Determined', 
        245, 79, 240, 6655); is the query I tried

Comment: How do I post the sql query?